# importing Csv into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and it works well when I import only three fields, but when I try to import more than 3 it does not work.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO forms (id, created_time, ad_id, ad_name, adset_id, adset_name, campaign_id, campaign_name, form_id, is_organic, specialist, full_name, email, city, country, date_of_birth, phone_number) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[10])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[11])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[12])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[13])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[14])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[15])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[16])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[17])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Comment: first use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`, now what error you are getting.

Comment: when i run the code with only 3 it is work like this .
mysql_query("INSERT INTO forms (id, created_time, ad_id) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

Comment: just echo the query as a string and try that query in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: when i use it as a 3 entry it is inserted in the database tables and when i use the 17 entry nothing gone in the database table so the issue must be here : 


    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    //

Comment: try to set second param to `0` in `fgetcsv` see if that helps

Comment: i get Server Error

Answer (score 0):

try this its work for you

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","));
```

instead of

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Comment: Please explain why this will help.

Comment: Perpahs your CSV file contains DOUBLE QUOTES.  The objective then would be to filter those double quotes from the string BEFORE creating a MYSQL query.

Answer (score 0):

What is `addslashes()` doing in this code? There's only one thing you need to escape when talking to a database, and that's single quotes (see `mysql_real_escape_string()`, mysqli_real_escape_string(), etc.) `addslashes` is for generating html, so it scribbles on your data in ways that you'll notice when it's too late. Since we're on it, you also shouldn't use the long-obsoleted `mysql_*` functions. Didn't you see the big red (ok pink) **Warning** in the documentation of [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)? Use `mysqli`, which is barely different if you don't use the object-oriented style. Third, you should use "prepared queries", not build the strings yourself. Much safer this way. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for an example.

So, finally to your question. To build a long string from lots of array elements, you could use a loop to append each element in turn. But a better way is to use `implode`: It combines array elements into a single string, with your choice of connecting string.

```
// Escape the first 18 columns of $data
$escaped = array_map("mysqli_real_escape_string", array_slice($data, 0, 18));
// Now pack them into the insert query
$querystring = "INSERT INTO forms (id, created_time, ad_id, ad_name, adset_id, adset_name, campaign_id, campaign_name, form_id, is_organic, specialist, full_name, email, city, country, date_of_birth, phone_number) 
    VALUES (" . implode(",", $escaped) . ")";
```